Why doesn't getStaticProps Next Js work when I call it at the app/page level?
I've been sitting here for 2 hours and I don't understand a damn thing. I have searched the whole internet and can't understand why getStaticProps doesn't work. First I used it at the component level and it didn't work. Then I found an article that said it should be used at the page level. That's what I did, but it didn't work for me again. I have Next version 14, maybe something has changed in this version or I'm blind and dumb.
app/(group)/rooms

import { RoomsPage } from '@/page/Rooms'
import { getCards } from '@/shared/api'
import { IRoomsCardAllData } from '@/shared/types'
import { GetStaticProps, Metadata } from 'next'
import { FC } from 'react'

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await getCards()
        return { props: { roomsData: res.data } }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return { props: { roomsData: [] } }
    }
}
export const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: 'Guest House | Номера',
}

interface Props {
    roomsData: IRoomsCardAllData[]
}

const Rooms: FC<Props> = ({ roomsData }) => {
    return <RoomsPage roomsData={roomsData} />
}

export default Rooms


Everything that is in getStaticProps does not seem to work. No errors are displayed, nor console.log is processed. I don’t know what to think?

Since your page is found inside the app folder I'll assume you are using the App Router.
If you were used to the older Pages Router, there are some things that have changed, especially when it comes to data fetching.
In your case, getStaticProps is no longer supported in the App Router and instead you should fetch your data directly on the component. This is because the App Router is leveraging React server components which allow for async code to be executed in them.
Just call your getCards directly inside the component:
import { RoomsPage } from '@/page/Rooms'
import { getCards } from '@/shared/api'
import { IRoomsCardAllData } from '@/shared/types'
import { GetStaticProps, Metadata } from 'next'
import { FC } from 'react'

export const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: 'Guest House | Номера',
}

interface Props {

}

const Rooms: FC<Props> = async ({}) => {
    const { data: roomsData } = await getCards()
    return <RoomsPage roomsData={roomsData} />
}

export default Rooms


Thanks for your reply. I think that's more like it.
const Rooms: FC<Props> = async({}) => {
    const { data: roomsData } = await getCards()
    return <RoomsPage roomsData={roomsData} />
}

Can you answer one more question if you don't mind? This solution will not be bad for SEO?

Nope, it does not affect SEO at all. This is in fact how Next.js applications with App Router should fetch data. If you need dynamic information in your metadata, you can use generateMetadata to fetch the data and set the metadata as well. Repeated calls to the same endpoint shouldn't be much of a problem, since Next.js does allow for request caching.
